# Gnuplot stdin and time data format?

Tags: gnuplot, stdin, datetime-format

I'm newbie here, and my english isn't too good - sorry.

I would plot graph and I have data in two columns (UNIX timestamp and float number). I would have time on X-axis.

When data are in a file, then I haven't problem. But when I use stdin, then gnuplot get me an error message:

> test2.plt", line 11: Need full using spec for x time data"

What's wrong?

Content of test1.plt (no problem with it):

```
set terminal png size 1600, 600
set output "graf.png"
set title  "Aktuální cena"
set ylabel "cena [$]"
set xlabel "Čas"

set xdata time
set timefmt "%s"
set format x "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S"
set xrange ["1366476024":"1366493178"]
plot 'b:/.../cpu.dat' using 1:2
```

Content of cpu.dat:

```
1366476024 123.1
1366476052 123.1
1366476080 123.23
1366476122 123.32
1366493178 126.28
```

Content of test2.plt (result in error message):

```
set terminal png size 1600, 600
set output "graf.png"
set title  "Aktuální cena"
set ylabel "cena [$]"
set xlabel "Čas"

set xdata time
set timefmt "%s"
set format x "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S"
set xrange ["1366476024":"1366493178"]
plot "-"
1366476024 123.1
1366476052 123.1
1366476080 123.23
1366476122 123.32
1366493178 126.28
e
```

Please, where is the problem?
I have gnuplot 4.6.3 on 64-bit Win7

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you declate `set xdata time` then you must use "using" in your plot statement. 
In your case , you only need to add "using 1:2":

```
plot "-" using 1:2
1366476024 123.1
1366476052 123.1
1366476080 123.23
1366476122 123.32
1366493178 126.28
e
```